# React - Why we don't need to include methods that use the prev state on React.memo areEqual?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Check the fetchCats method of this custom hook:

```
const useFetchCats = () => {
   const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);
 
   const cursor = useRef(new Date());

   const fetchCats = async () => {
       ...

       const newCats = await api.getCats(cursor.current);

       ... update next cursor etc.

       setCats((prevCats) => [...newCats, ...prevCats]);
   };

   return [cats, fetchCats];
}
```

Now, in order to use it, imagine you have this component:

```
import { isEqual } from "lodash";

export default function CatsViewer() {
    const [cats, fetchCats] = useFetchCats();

    useOtherHookThatConsumesContext(); // just to justify the memoized child

    return <MemoizedCatsViewer cats={cats} fetchCats={fetchCats} />;
}

const MemoizedCats = memo(
   (cats, fetchCats) => {
      ...

      return <CatList data={cats} onEndReached={fetchCats} />;
   }, 
   (prevProps, nextProps) =>
       isEqual(prevProps.cats, nextProps.cats)
);
```

This code works without errors even with the fact that we are not including `prevProps.fetchCats === nextProps.fetchCats` in the memo's areEqual callback. Why is that? I mean, I think it has to be related to the way I am accessing the prevState... but, whats the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Why you think you have to use === in memo callback? You're using isEqual instead, don't understand your confusion :( :)

Comment: I mean you can pass whatever you want in there. For example returning true always would make the code work too but the functionality of memo entirely unused.

Comment: why? I mean, with lodash isEqual I am just deep comparing the prev and the next data.

Comment: @fast-reflexes also this memoization will prevent the re-renders caused due to the useOtherHookThatConsumesContext()

Comment: No, check the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). Only rerenders caused by changed props will be skipped, not rerenders due to context or state change.

Comment: @fast-reflexes yeah yeah, I know that I can only use props in the memo callback. I mean that, as I am using that hook in the parent, the child will be re-rendered by a state change in the context (that is consumed in the parent). The main purpose of my memo is to only re-render the child when its props change, not because of a parent re-render.

Comment: My main confusion is that, without including the fetchCats method equality, it seems that I can use a totally re-created (its not re-created, thats my confusion) `setCats` inside its body.

Comment: State setters are referentially identical on every render :) If the setter comes from the same setState call, it will be the same on every render, as opposed to the state value which will NOT be referentially identical between renders.

Comment: @fast-reflexes that is, thx. Same thing that happens with useRef variables.